# Running android app in samsung device

Tags: android

Environment:

- My system Os is Windows XP
- IDE is eclipse juno
- Usb connector is Nokia

Now I want to run android application in the device. For that I follow the below commands

1) adb kill-server

2) adb start-server

3) adb devices

But it is not showing the device name in the list of attached devices, it is showing only emulators. Can you give me any suggestions to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings->Applications->Development.

Check on USB Debugging.

and install the drivers and Kies samsung software in your PC.

Answer (score -1):

If you develop in a linux environment, drivers are not needed. Try dual-boot or booting a [live distro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs) if you are not comfortable giving up windows.

Comment: Suggesting a new OS to resolve an issue with ADB is not a good answer.  Factual answers are preferred here and the facts are that Linux has as many problems with ADB as any other desktop OS.  Try searching.